# Adding a quit function to finished code

Tags: python

I wrote up [Battleship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29) for fun, and as soon as I was finished I forgot to add a quit function in case the player wanted to quit before he/she finished the game. Is there a way to add a `quit` function to my code or do I have to completely redo the entire program (something like "would you like to quit? y/n")?

```
import copy, random

def print_board(s,board):

    #Find out if you are printing the computer or user board
    player = "Computer"
    if s == "u":
        player = "User"

    print "The " + player + "'s board look like this: \n"

    #Print the horizontal numbers
    print " ",
    for i in range(10):
        print "  " + str(i+1) + "  ",
    print "\n"

    for i in range(10):

        #Print the vertical line number
        if i != 9:
            print str(i+1) + "  ",
        else:
            print str(i+1) + " ",

        #Print the board values, and cell dividers
        for j in range(10):
            if board[i][j] == -1:
                print ' ',
            elif s == "u":
                print board[i][j],
            elif s == "c":
                if board[i][j] == "*" or board[i][j] == "$":
                    print board[i][j],
                else:
                    print " ",

            if j != 9:
                print " | ",
        print

        #Print a horizontal line
        if i != 9:
            print "   ----------------------------------------------------------"
        else:
            print

def user_place_ships(board,ships):

    for ship in ships.keys():

        #Get coordinates from user and vlidate the postion
        valid = False
        while(not valid):

            print_board("u",board)
            print "Placing a/an " + ship
            x,y = get_coor()
            ori = v_or_h()
            valid = validate(board,ships[ship],x,y,ori)
            if not valid:
                print "Cannot place a ship there.\nPlease take a look at the board and try again."
                raw_input("Hit ENTER to continue")

        #Place the ship
        board = place_ship(board,ships[ship],ship[0],ori,x,y)
        print_board("u",board)

    raw_input("Done placing user ships. Hit ENTER to continue")
    return board


def computer_place_ships(board,ships):

    for ship in ships.keys():

        #Generate random coordinates and validate the postion
        valid = False
        while(not valid):

            x = random.randint(1,10)-1
            y = random.randint(1,10)-1
            o = random.randint(0,1)
            if o == 0:
                ori = "v"
            else:
                ori = "h"
            valid = validate(board,ships[ship],x,y,ori)

        #Place the ship
        print "Computer placing a/an " + ship
        board = place_ship(board,ships[ship],ship[0],ori,x,y)

    return board


def place_ship(board,ship,s,ori,x,y):

    #Place ship based on orientation
    if ori == "v":
        for i in range(ship):
            board[x+i][y] = s
    elif ori == "h":
        for i in range(ship):
            board[x][y+i] = s

    return board

def validate(board,ship,x,y,ori):

    #Validate if the ship can be placed at given coordinates
    if ori == "v" and x+ship > 10:
        return False
    elif ori == "h" and y+ship > 10:
        return False
    else:
        if ori == "v":
            for i in range(ship):
                if board[x+i][y] != -1:
                    return False
        elif ori == "h":
            for i in range(ship):
                if board[x][y+i] != -1:
                    return False

    return True

def v_or_h():

    #Get ship orientation from the user
    while(True):
        user_input = raw_input("vertical or horizontal (v,h) ? ")
        if user_input == "v" or user_input == "h":
            return user_input
        else:
            print "Invalid input. Please only enter v or h"

def get_coor():

    while (True):
        user_input = raw_input("Please enter coordinates (row,col) ? ")
        try:
            #See that user entered two values separated by a comma
            coor = user_input.split(",")
            if len(coor) != 2:
                raise Exception("Invalid entry, too few/many coordinates.");

            #Check that the two values are integers
            coor[0] = int(coor[0])-1
            coor[1] = int(coor[1])-1

            #Check that the values of the integers are between 1 and 10 for both coordinates
            if coor[0] > 9 or coor[0] < 0 or coor[1] > 9 or coor[1] < 0:
                raise Exception("Invalid entry. Please use values between 1 to 10 only.")

            #If everything is OK, return coordinates
            return coor

        except ValueError:
            print "Invalid entry. Please enter only numeric values for coordinates"
        except Exception as e:
            print e

def make_move(board,x,y):

    #Make a move on the board and return the result, hit, miss or try again for repeat hit
    if board[x][y] == -1:
        return "miss"
    elif board[x][y] == '*' or board[x][y] == '$':
        return "try again"
    else:
        return "hit"

def user_move(board):

    #Get coordinates from the user and try to make a move.
    #If move is a hit, check ship sunk and win condition
    while(True):
        x,y = get_coor()
        res = make_move(board,x,y)
        if res == "hit":
            print "Hit at " + str(x+1) + "," + str(y+1)
            check_sink(board,x,y)
            board[x][y] = '$'
            if check_win(board):
                return "WIN"
        elif res == "miss":
            print "Sorry, " + str(x+1) + "," + str(y+1) + " is a miss."
            board[x][y] = "*"
        elif res == "try again":
            print "Sorry, that coordinate was already hit. Please try again"

        if res != "try again":
            return board

def computer_move(board):

    #Generate user coordinates from the user and try to make move.
    #If the move is a hit, check ship sunk and win condition
    while(True):
        x = random.randint(1,10)-1
        y = random.randint(1,10)-1
        res = make_move(board,x,y)
        if res == "hit":
            print "Hit at " + str(x+1) + "," + str(y+1)
            check_sink(board,x,y)
            board[x][y] = '$'
            if check_win(board):
                return "WIN"
        elif res == "miss":
            print "Sorry, " + str(x+1) + "," + str(y+1) + " is a miss."
            board[x][y] = "*"

        if res != "try again":

            return board

def check_sink(board,x,y):

    #Figure out what ship was hit
    if board[x][y] == "A":
        ship = "Aircraft Carrier"
    elif board[x][y] == "B":
        ship = "Battleship"
    elif board[x][y] == "S":
        ship = "Submarine"
    elif board[x][y] == "D":
        ship = "Destroyer"
    elif board[x][y] == "P":
        ship = "Patrol Boat"

    #Mark cell as hit and check if sunk
    board[-1][ship] -= 1
    if board[-1][ship] == 0:
        print ship + " Sunk"


def check_win(board):

    #Simple for loop to check all cells in 2D board.
    #If any cell contains a char that is not a hit or a miss, return false
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            if board[i][j] != -1 and board[i][j] != '*' and board[i][j] != '$':
                return False
    return True

def main():

    #Types of ships
    ships = {"Aircraft Carrier":5,
             "Battleship":4,
             "Submarine":3,
             "Destroyer":3,
             "Patrol Boat":2}

    #Set up blank 10x10 board
    board = []
    for i in range(10):
        board_row = []
        for j in range(10):
            board_row.append(-1)
        board.append(board_row)

    #Set up user and computer boards
    user_board = copy.deepcopy(board)
    comp_board = copy.deepcopy(board)

    #Add ships as the last element in the array
    user_board.append(copy.deepcopy(ships))
    comp_board.append(copy.deepcopy(ships))

    #Ship placement
    user_board = user_place_ships(user_board,ships)
    comp_board = computer_place_ships(comp_board,ships)

    #Game main loop
    while(1):

        #User move
        print_board("c",comp_board)
        comp_board = user_move(comp_board)

        #Check if a user has won
        if comp_board == "WIN":
            print "User WON! :)"
            quit()

        #Display current computer board
        print_board("c",comp_board)
        raw_input("To end user turn hit ENTER")

        #Computer move
        user_board = computer_move(user_board)

        #Check if computer move
        if user_board == "WIN":
            print "Computer WON! :("
            quit()

        #Display user board
        print_board("u",user_board)
        raw_input("To end computer turn hit ENTER")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: At what moment(s) would you want to give them the option to quit?

Comment: in the main program is where I want to implement it where it says "to end your turn hit enter", I've been trying to add "or do you want to quit?"

Comment: You could have it say `Press 1 to quit or 2 to continue and end your turn` and handle the input right after that

Comment: Many command prompts have a built-in abort command, usually Control-C. So you don't necessarily need an explicit quit option; the user can already quit whenever he wants.

Comment: yes that is true but I want a nicer way of quitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your while(1) loop with this:

```
  selection = 'n'

  while (selection != 'y'):

     # Do game stuff

     print '\nQuit? (y/n)\n'         

     selection=raw_input('\n>> ')
```